# Update table with multiple records using single update query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am retrieving set of records to update the table.

result set look like this,

```
MemId          username             memberName
 -----         -----------          -------------
1              James                James cam                
2              Peter                Peter Parker
3              Allen                Allen Martin
4
.
.
.
n rows
```

i am getting above result set using select Query.
i want to update username with memberName column with single update query.

Comment: you mean replace username by membername?

Comment: yes replace username by membername

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    UPDATE table SET username = memberName
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cc0e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Update goes like this (leave away the WHERE clause *if you are sure what you do*

```
UPDATE table SET username = memberName WHERE MemId > 4
```